# Not working Security::setDefaultAdmin() funtion

Tags: php, silverstripe

```
Security::setDefaultAdmin('admin','password')
```

this function is include in config.php. why cant login into cms?

Comment: The docs says it only works in `dev` mode.
Is your site set to be in `dev` mode? (check the `SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` environment variable)